# Is there an API to the new macOS translation system?

Tags: macos, text-to-speech, translate, macos-monterey

In the newest editions of Safari (and other Apple apps, like Books) you can select some text, then control-click for a context menu, and then "Translate" the text. You get two things:

1. The translated text
2. Play buttons that read you either language in nice Siri-like (realistic) text-to-speech.

Is there an API to do this that's available to our own apps?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe this is available as a developer API at this current time